# iOS App Landscape Mode Launch Image Not Showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, launchimage

I'm developing an iOS app only in landscape mode. I'm loading the Launchscreen images as : Default@2x.png, Default-568h@2x.png, Default-667h@2x.png, Default-736h@3x.png.

The problem is that whenever i launch the app in iPhone6 or 6+ it gets the screen dimensions from iphone5.

P.S. I've tried using Images.Xcassets but it did not worked for iPhones<6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2) provided by Apple and confirm all your images are in required sizes or not. Also go through image naming conventions are approprite or not.

Because Launch Images should be picked up automatically as per device and its orientation.

Here is the link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2

Answer (score 0):

If your app is landscape only you MUST check option 'Portrait' on 'Device Orientation' section in General tab of app settings. Then you need setup orientation settings for all view controllers:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft |
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

In Images.xcassets you need to put all images for iOS 7 & 8. After that app will be launched with proper launch image. Note that `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` must be equivalent for launch image orientation.